# Two MySQL databases in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a problem, i want to connect 2 databases in Python at the same time. The two databases are identical. At any given time , one of the two primary and the other secondary stations . If the primary fails, the secondary station takes over.

I have no idea where to start. Creating 2 databases is not the problem but taking it into python is the challenge. Thank you guys!

Comment: Do you know how to connect to one database with python. There are all sorts of ways you might do so. 
If you do, then it will help give answers that will match what you are already doing.  If not, then try getting that working first.

Comment: hi, yes i know how to do that, but i cant figure out how to connect 2 databases with primary and secondary things, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have to install the mysql driver for python. Once installed, you could create two connections this way:

```
import mysql.connector
con1 = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', password='tiger', host='127.0.0.1',database='example')
con2 = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', password='tiger', host='127.0.0.1',database='example2')

connections = [con1, con2]
```

Once this is done, you could try querying one of them and if something is wrong, you query the other one. Like this

```
for connection in connections:
    try:
        runQuery(connection)
        break;
    except:
        continue;
```